# How to make Spring Integration HTTP outbound-channel-adapter participate in Global Transaction

Tags: java, jms, http-post, message-queue, spring-integration

I have the following `Spring Integration` configuration. what i am doing here is `dequeuing` the message from a topic and sending it to some HTTP locaiton after transformation.

`JMS Connection Factory` is configured as follows:

```
<bean id="inboundCF" 
class="org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory">
    <constructor-arg index="0">
        <jee:jndi-lookup jndi-name="java:comp/resource/ABC_AQ/XATopicConnectionFactories/XATCF" />
    </constructor-arg>
    <property name="sessionCacheSize" value="3" />
</bean>
<bean id="txInboundCF"
class="org.springframework.jms.connection.TransactionAwareConnectionFactoryProxy">
    <property name="targetConnectionFactory" ref="inboundCF" />
<property name="synchedLocalTransactionAllowed" value="true" />
</bean>
```

and `Message Listener Container` is configured as follows:

```
<bean id="jmsInboundContainer"
class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer"
destroy-method="destroy">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="txInboundCF" />
    <property name="destination" ref="inboundDestination" />
    <property name="pubSubDomain" value="true" />
    <property name="sessionTransacted" value="true" />
    <property name="errorHandler" ref="errorHandlerService" />
    <property name="subscriptionDurable" value="true" />
    <property name="durableSubscriptionName" value="mySub" />
    <property name="cacheLevel" value="3" />
</bean>
<int-jms:message-driven-channel-adapter channel="jmsInChannel"
container="jmsInboundContainer" acknowledge="transacted" />
```

and `HTTP outbound adapter` is configured as follows:

```
<int-http:outbound-channel-adapter channel="httpOutChannel" url="http://www.example.com/test" http-method="POST" charset="UTF-8" />
```

It is working fine in case of happy scenario. However it is not rolling back the http post messages but jms messages are rolling back in `topic` in case of any exception occurred after that. So, `http:outbound-channel-adapter` is not participating in global transaction.

How can i achieve this. Appriciate any help in this regard.

Secondly, i can found the following log entries in my log file but messages are getting dequeued successfully.

```
[23/09/2013 14:27:51] WARN [Thread-102] CachingConnectionFactory.onException(301) | Encountered a JMSException - resetting the underlying JMS Connection
javax.jms.JMSException: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

at oracle.jms.AQjmsExceptionListener.run(AQjmsExceptionListener.java:222)
[23/09/2013 14:27:51] WARN [jmsInboundContainer-9] DefaultMessageListenerContainer.handleListenerSetupFailure(821) | Setup of JMS message listener invoker failed for destination 'MY_TOPIC' - trying to recover. Cause: JMS-115: Consumer is closed
```

Answer (score 6):

It's not an issue of `<int-http:outbound-channel-adapter>`. HTTP protocol isn't transactional by definition. So, if you send request to some URL and get 200 OK, that means that your request was delivered to remote server successfully.
However Spring Integration has trick for you: [Transaction Synchronization](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/2.2.5.RELEASE/reference/html/transactions.html#transaction-synchronization)
IT may looks like this:

```
<jms:inbound-channel-adapter>
    <int:poller>
        <int:transactional synchronization-factory="syncFactory"/>
    </int:poller>
</jms:inbound-channel-adapter>

<int:transaction-synchronization-factory id="syncFactory">
      <int:after-commit channel="httpOutboundChannel"/>
</int:transaction-synchronization-factory>
```

And your `<jms:inbound-channel-adapter>` may send a Message to some empty handler, e.g. `nullChannel`

Comment: i understand. but what if the message is not successfully delivered to http. So the transaction will be rollback??

Comment: You have asked about 'rolling back' successful HTTP request... To rollback transaction when HTTP request fails is a different story. So, I think it is another separate topic

Comment: your solution is not rolling back successful HTTP request rather it is originating the HTTP post after commit. See the subject of question what i asked for.

Comment: Try to explain what you want to achieve via other way, because words `not rolling back successful HTTP request` sound very odd...